# Can Google Document AI classify documents?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I'm playing with Google **Document AI** and when I read some documentation from Google and other sources I often see a statement that Document AI can **classify** documents, not only extract the data by labels. However, I don't see how I can achieve that.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update on the product: Document AI now supports creating [Custom Document Classifier](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/document-ai-workbench-adds-custom-document-classifier) processors in GA which allows classification of custom document types. So you won't need to use AutoML Image or Text Classification for classifying documents that don't have a dedicated Specialized Splitter/Classifier.

Here's the instructions for how to create one.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/build-custom-classification-processor

Comment: Google Document AI custom classifier works really well on a good set of documents with a similar structure. I wish there were an API to upload labeled documents into a dataset.

Comment: The API doesn't currently support uploading documents to a dataset only. But the [`processorVersions.train()`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.processors.processorVersions/train) method does support providing a dataset to train a processor.

This page has a code sample for REST/Python https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/train-processor#train_processor_version

Answer (score 2):

You can perform documents classification when using what is called [Specialized Processors](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#specialized_processors).

There is this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/docai-specialized-processors-python) which explains how to deal with those specialized processors (including document classification).

Another way of creating documents classification is using [Vertex AI AutoML image classification](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training-overview#automl) where you can create a dataset of documents images (ie. scanned documents) and train a model that will get a new document image and predict if it is document type 1, type 2, type 3, etc.

Comment: I saw this video and it's still unclear how to get it to work. I don't see any mentions of a document type in the resulting JSON that I get from Document AI.

Comment: the steps to get it to work are on the codelab I mention on the answer.

Comment: Here is more information on handling the Document object response for Splitting/Classification. https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#splitting

You have to use a processor that performs Classification such as the Procurement Splitter/Classifier or Lending Splitter/Classifier.
https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_procurement-document-splitter

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_lending-splitter-classifier

Comment: Do I understand correctly that a custom processor cannot classify documents?

Comment: A Custom Document Extractor cannot classify documents, it can only extract entities. Refer to the release notes for updates on future Custom Processors that can classify documents. https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/release-notes